# given value is not suitable for child module variable : string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using tags here like this:

```
module "ingest_system" {
  source                = "../../modules/ingest_system"
  for_each              = local.systems
  . . . .
  tags                  = local.tags
}
```

I get the following error:

```
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "tags" defined
│ at ../../modules/ingest_system/variables.tf:25,1-16: element
│ "environment": string required.
```

That's how the tags are defined:

```
variable "tags" {
  type = map(string)
}
variable "environment_name" {
  type = string
}
```

```
  tags = {
    cost_reference : "something",
    environment : local.env
  }
```

How should I modify it? Should I just `string` instead of `map(string)` but its in a dictionary form so I am uncertain

Comment: I think the issue is at 
environment: local.env
This local.env should be a string. Can you confirm that it's a string? Also, can you confirm that the line variables.tf:25 is the variable "enviroment"?

Comment: If you want to test it, you can do: "type = any" for tags variable